# How to read Date from an XML file and Parse it using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

The xml file is having the following structure

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="TestFile.xsl"?>
<RootElement>  
  <Date FileModified="7/2/2010 12:54:53 PM" />
  <Child Name="A"/>
  <Child Name="B"/>
  <Child Name="C"/>
  <Child Name="D"/>
  <Child Name="E"/>
</RootElement>
```

I need to read the date attribute value from the file  and pass the to

```
var d=new Date(  date );
```

Here is my xsl file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head></head>
  <body>
    <center>
      <b>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var d_names = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday","Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
          var m_names = new Array("January", "February", "March","April", "May", "June", "July", "August","September","October","November", "December");

          var d = new Date(-----------); // here i need to get the date from the xsl file

          var curr_day = d.getDay();
          var curr_date = d.getDate();
          var sup = "";
          if (curr_date == 1 || curr_date == 21 || curr_date ==31)
          {
          sup = "st";
          }
          else if (curr_date == 2 || curr_date == 22)
          {
      sup = "nd";
      }
          else if (curr_date == 3 || curr_date == 23)
          {
          sup = "rd";
          }
          else
          {
          sup = "th";
          }
          var curr_month = d.getMonth();
          var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
          var curr_hour=d.getHours();
          var curr_period="AM"
          if(curr_hour>12)
          {
          curr_hour=curr_hour-12;
          curr_period="PM"
          }
          document.write(d_names[curr_day]+ "&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;" +curr_date + "<sup>"+ sup + "  </sup> " + m_names[curr_month] + "&#160;&#160;" + curr_year+ "&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;"+curr_hour+" : "+d.getMinutes()+" : "+d.getSeconds()+" "+curr_period);
        </script>
      </b>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="//Child">
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <b>SampleTable</b>
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="RGB(0,0,127)" >
              <th width="5">
                <font color="white">S.No</font>
              </th>
              <th width="250">
                <font color="white"> Name</font>
              </th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select ="//Child">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <xsl:number value="position()" format="01"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </table>
        </xsl:when >
        <xsl:otherwise ></xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose >
    </center>
  </body >
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is there any way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var d = new Date('<xsl:value-of select="RootElement/Date/@FileModified"/>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can get de desire result with pure XSLT, like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="m_names">
        <January/><February/><March/><April/><May/><June/><July/><August/><September/><October/><November/><December/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="d_names">
        <Sunday/><Monday/><Tuesday/><Wednesday/><Thursday/><Friday/><Saturday/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="modules" select="'033614625035034025036146'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="date" select="/*/*/@FileModified"/>
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring-before($date,'/')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring-before(substring-after($date,'/'),'/')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring($date,7 + string-length($date) - 22,4)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="calc-day" select="(($year - 1) mod 7 +
                                       (floor(($year - 1) div 4) - 3 * floor((floor(($year - 1) div 100) + 1) div 4)) mod 7 +
                                       substring($modules,
                                                 12 * ($year mod 4 = 0 and $year mod 100 != 0) + $month,
                                                 1) +
                                       $day mod 7)
                                       mod 7 + 1"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <center>
                    <b>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(
                                                     name(document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='d_names']/*[$calc-day]),
                                                     '&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;',
                                                     $day
                                                    )"/>
                        <sup>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="$day = 1 or $day = 21">st</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="$day = 2 or $day = 22">nd</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="$day = 3 or $day = 23">rd</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>th</xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </sup>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(
                                                     '&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;',
                                                     name(document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='m_names']/*[number($month)]),
                                                     '&#160;&#160;',
                                                     $year,
                                                     '&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;',
                                                     substring($date,12 + string-length($date) - 22,2),
                                                     ' : ',
                                                     substring($date,15 + string-length($date) - 22,2),
                                                     ' : ',
                                                     substring($date,18 + string-length($date) - 22,2),
                                                     ' ',
                                                     substring($date,string-length($date)-1)
                                                    )"/>
                    </b>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </center>
            </body >
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Child[1]">
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <b>SampleTable</b>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="RGB(0,0,127)" >
                <th width="5">
                    <font color="white">S.No</font>
                </th>
                <th width="250">
                    <font color="white"> Name</font>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../Child" mode="child"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Child" mode="child">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:number value="position()" format="01"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**: Date extraction could be less verbose if you use a better date format.

Comment: Can u please explain the use of
<xsl:variable name="modules" select="'033614625035034025036146'"/> 
element

Comment: @Pramodh: I used a method to calculate the day of the week described http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_para_calcular_el_d%C3%ADa_de_la_semana . You can choose someone else if you want. So, `$modules` hold some offset by month (normal year and leap year).